# Java 14 Switch-Expression with default case

Tags: java, java-14

How can I declare a switch case as default, with the new Java 14 Switch Expressions?

All I want is:

```
enum States {
    PLAY, STOP
}
...
States state = ...

switch (state) {
    case PLAY -> { run(); }
    case STOP, default -> { stop(); }
}
```

Which doesn't compile. It compiles with Java 17 ***Preview***-Features, but that can't be the solution?! I really want to avoid using unfinished features.

It should be the equivalent to the old-style switch statement:

```
switch (state) {
    case PLAY: run(); break;
    case STOP: // <-- No extra "break;". Intentional fall-through!
    default: stop(); break;
}
```

Is that possible with plain Java 14 (or maybe 17)?

Comment: If you want `STOP` to behave the same as `default` then just omit the `STOP` case, and it will be part of the default.

Comment: @khelwood That's of course correct, but not as expressive as explicitly mentioning it.

Comment: you already found out that it is a preview feature of Java 17 (and 18) - part of [Pattern Matching for switch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/preview/specs/patterns-switch-jls.html) - so it is not possible to use it with previous versions

Comment: What is `state`? An `enum`?

Comment: Yes, it's an enum.

Comment: Then, if you don’t want to write just `default ->` because you want to be “as expressive as explicitly mentioning it”, why don’t you list *all* remaining cases and omit `default`? Oh, I see, you edited the question and added the definition. So, there’s no reason for a `default` at all. Just use `switch (state) { case PLAY -> run(); case STOP -> stop(); }` or, if you consider potential modifications of the `enum` type: `switch (state) { case PLAY -> run(); case STOP -> stop(); default -> throw new AssertionError(); }`

Answer (score 2):

Do not think that is possible. An alternative is to  just include stop() in both cases:

```java
switch (state) {
    case PLAY -> run();
    case STOP -> stop();
    default -> stop();
}
```